# Displaying custom UIView in a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am creating a UIView which I want to display in my view controller. I have created the UIView and it shows, but the problems I have now are:

1. When I call the UIView in my view controller, I can no longer interact with the elements of the view controller. The `CustomView` I created has completely prevented the interaction with my view controller and I want to be able to interact with the UIViewController.
2. I want to hide the status bar which includes the battery percentage and network bar and other things so the view completely covers them. I implemented a code to cover them, but it returns an error.

below is my code

```
class SliderView: CustomView {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderText: UILabel!

    override func initialize() {
        super.initialize()

        let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: name, bundle: .main)
        nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)

        self.addSubview(self.containerView)
        self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            self.containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            self.containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            ])
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return sliderImage.frame.contains(point)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

  // THIS THROWS an error 'Property does not override any property from its superclass'
}
```

my UIView is called in my Viewcontroller like

```
 weak var sliderView: SliderView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let sliderView = SliderView()
        self.view.addSubview(sliderView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sliderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            sliderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            sliderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            sliderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            ])
        self.sliderView = sliderView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sliderView.sliderText.text = "HOOOOO WORKS"
}
```

Comment: `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }` should probably go in the viewcontroller not the uiview.

Comment: As for first point not sure. maybe your custom view is covering the whole of the uiviewcontroller view hence captures the user touch

Comment: Exactly what @iOSer said, `prefersStatusBarHidden` is a property of UIViewController, not of UIView. Is this the only problem you're experiencing, or are you actually having problems handling interaction between the VC and the view?

Comment: I figured the `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }` was a uiviewcontroller property but the first problem remains unsolved @iOSer @JillevdW

Comment: What `CustomView` class does? (that you are inheriting the SliderView)

Comment: @King provide a background color to `CustomView` and execute the code. If it covers the whole of the screen then the items you want to interact with are probably hiding beneath the `CustomView` hence unreachable

Comment: I have fixed it and it works now but now on a contrary, I cannot interact with the UIView I created

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sliderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            sliderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            sliderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            sliderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            ])
```

Your custom view is covering the whole `UIViewController`. Therefore, it is not possible to interact with the `UIViewController`.

Just try to replace the second constraint with the following to cover only half of the screen's height:

```
sliderView.topAnchor.constraint.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.5)
```

This is just a suggestion to see the difference, i.e., not a solution.